# How to replace test functions in py.test while collecting tests?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module with test functions and I want to write `conftest.py` file to decorate all functions in the module after the collection phase and before test run. And I do not want to edit the module with test functions.
I tried it this way:

#### test_foo.py

```
def test_foo ():
    assert 1 == 42
```

#### conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests (metafunc):
    def test_bar ():
        assert 1 == 2
    metafunc.function = test_bar
```

When I run tests, I get this:

```
==================================== FAILURES =====================================
____________________________________ test_foo _____________________________________

    def test_foo ():
>       assert 1 == 42
E       assert 1 == 42
```

But I expected assertion error about `1 == 2`.

Comment: How to do *what*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to decorate each function in a module at the collection phase and I don't want to edit module with tests - only the `conftest.py` file.

Comment: Ok, but *to what end*?

Comment: I have test classes with tests and setup methods for them. I need to run all setup methods in the module just after collection phase - to make shared fixture - and to store result of setup method for according test method.

Comment: Then could you provide an example that *actually demonstrates that*? Why do you need to do this dynamically?

Comment: Unfortunately, test-class instances that I got after collection (to run `setup` with them) are not the same as test-class instances, which are used in testrun. So, I can't pass data through the object and I decided to wrap test objects in decorator with results of setup methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102700/discussion-between-timur-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: No, thank you; please edit the question with a [mcve] that actually shows the problem you're trying to solve, to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I can not make MC&V example for the general problem, so I reduced this problem to another one: the problem of changing `function` attribute of metafunction. This question is MC&V.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a certain function before *a test*, define a *fixture* and use the fixture name as test parameter.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def fixture1():
    assert 1 == 2


def test_foo(fixture1):
    assert 1 == 42
```

Output:

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def fixture1():
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2
```

If you want to run a certain function before *each test*, define a *fixture* with `autouse=True`. I think this is what you want.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fixture1():
    assert 1 == 2


def test_foo():
    assert 1 == 42
```

Output:

```
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def fixture1():
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2
```

If you want a *custom test decorator*, use standard decorator syntax.

```
def my_test_decorator(test):
    def wrapper():
        assert 1 == 2

    return wrapper


@my_test_decorator
def test_foo():
    assert 1 == 42
```

Output:

```
    def wrapper():
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not what I wanted.
I need to decorate each function in a module at the collection phase.

Comment: Also I don't want to edit module with test - just the `confrest.py` file.
Sorry for obscure question.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to replace the pytest item's `runtest` method.